# Getting Getting "main" java.lang.NullPointerException while launching uiautomatorviewer

Tags: appium-android, uiautomatorviewer

I am using java 8 and all the environment variables are set correctly. But getting below error. Please help to proceed.

[image: error]

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this issue, modify the uiautomatorviewer.bat comment find_java.bat and set java_exe = xxx\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin\java.exe The other parts are not modified and can run normally. Like this:

```
rem Check we have a valid Java.exe in the path.
set java_exe=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin\java.exe
rem call ..\lib\find_java.bat
if not defined java_exe goto :EOF
```

By the way, note that the number of bits in java.exe should be the same as the number of bits in swt.jar under the SDK. When repeated operations still report errors, please clear the cache by running sdkmanager.bat in the C:xxx\android-sdk\tools\bin directory Run uiautomatorviewer again to return to normal.